# Ansible suddenly uses svr4pkg as a backend of yum

Tags: ansible, yum, ansible-facts

Declared **YUM** task as below:

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars:
  tasks:

  - name: install package
    yum:
        name: ntp
        state: present
```

Ran following command:

```sh
ansible-playbook test.yml -i localhost, --connection=local -vvvv
```

Receiving error message:

```
TASK [install package] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/osuser/dod/test.yml:6
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/setup.py
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: osuser
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python && sleep 0'
Running svr4pkg as the backend for the yum action plugin
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/packaging/os/svr4pkg.py
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python && sleep 0'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "pkg_mgr": "svr4pkg"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "category": false,
            "name": "ntp",
            "proxy": null,
            "response_file": null,
            "src": null,
            "state": "present",
            "zone": "all"
        }
    },
    "msg": "src is required when state=present",
    "name": "ntp"
```

Note the following message in debug:

> Running svr4pkg as the backend for the yum action plugin

Ansible decided to use "**srv4pkg**" module (which requires `src` parameter) as backend of **yum**.

***Workaround:***
Set `use_backend: yum` parameter on yum module... if possible ! (I cannot modify the yaml file in my real usage).

Running Ansible 2.7.15 on CentOS 7.6.. with yum installed so there is absolutely no reason `svr4pkg` as a back-end (which is not supported/documented by yum module).

However, as it seems to be defined as an ansible_fact, I have done following test (result is filtered):

```sh
ansible -i localhost, all -m setup -k
```

```
SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_distribution": "CentOS",
        "ansible_distribution_file_parsed": true,
        "ansible_distribution_file_path": "/etc/redhat-release",
        "ansible_distribution_file_variety": "RedHat",
        "ansible_distribution_major_version": "7",
        "ansible_distribution_release": "Core",
        "ansible_distribution_version": "7.6.1810",
        "ansible_os_family": "RedHat",
        "ansible_pkg_mgr": "svr4pkg",
        "ansible_python_version": "2.7.5",
        "module_setup": true
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

Any clue of the reason and how to enforce `ansible_pkg_mgr` ?

Comment: There is absolutely no way your actual error can be related to your example task. Yum module is..... yum module. This could eventually happen with a task using the agnostic `package` module although I am not quite sure. IMO, there is somewhere in your playbook/role an include based on target OS and the detection is having problems (or was forced in a variable as Solaris). This is not related to ansible but to your inventory or code. You should inspect for changes there. Running ansible with -vvv might give you some clues on where this task is taken from exactly.

Comment: well. I insist .. that's what happens !
Note that when I use `use_backend: yum` the error gone... which prooves that computed `pkg_mgr_name`  in file `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/module_utils/facts/system/pkg_mgr.py` is somewhat wrong, or overridden somewhere else !

Comment: My apologies: yum module can effectively select a backend. But srv4pkg is not one of them (and that is why is failing). So either your server is mistakenly reporting this in his `ansible_pkg_mgr` facts (and you have to find out why), or someone as set the `ansible_pkg_mgr` var in your inventory for this server.

Comment: I don't use inventory as I run ansible task using `ansible-playbook medias.yml -i localhost, --connection=local ...` so the question is : where the `ansible_pkg_mgr` fact can be defined to `svr4pkg` (provided that this is a fresh CentOS install) ??

Comment: edited with more info / debug output etc..

Comment: Do you have anything on your localhost in `/etc/ansible/facts.d` ?

Comment: No. The directory does not even exist. Seems it's a bug on ansible2.7/centos 7x combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by upgrading to Ansible 2.8+.

See https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/49184 when multiple package managers are available on system.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this distribution is shipped with `yum` and `svr4pkg` as we can see below:

```sh
$ ll /usr/bin/yum
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 801 Nov  5  2018 /usr/bin/yum
$ ll /usr/sbin/pkgadd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 207342 Jul  2 16:12 /usr/sbin/pkgadd
```

So the last available package manager resolved is kept and take precedence `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/module_utils/facts/system/pkg_mgr.py`

```py
# A list of dicts.  If there is a platform with more than one
# package manager, put the preferred one last.  If there is an
# ansible module, use that as the value for the 'name' key.
PKG_MGRS = [{'path': '/usr/bin/yum', 'name': 'yum'},
            {'path': '/usr/bin/dnf', 'name': 'dnf'},
            {'path': '/usr/bin/apt-get', 'name': 'apt'},
            {'path': '/usr/sbin/pkgadd', 'name': 'svr4pkg'},
            [...]

    def collect(self, module=None, collected_facts=None):
        facts_dict = {}
        collected_facts = collected_facts or {}

        pkg_mgr_name = 'unknown'
        for pkg in PKG_MGRS:
            if os.path.exists(pkg['path']):
                pkg_mgr_name = pkg['name']

        # Handle distro family defaults when more than one package manager is
        # installed, the ansible_fact entry should be the default package
        # manager provided by the distro.
        if collected_facts['ansible_os_family'] == "RedHat":
            if pkg_mgr_name not in ('yum', 'dnf'):
                pkg_mgr_name = self._check_rh_versions(pkg_mgr_name, collected_facts)

        [...]

        facts_dict['pkg_mgr'] = pkg_mgr_name
        return facts_dict
```

So it seems to be an unmanaged case on ansible.

However, I still have no idea on how to enforce the right value !